# How to add JPanel into another JPanel with vertical scrollpane at runtime?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, flowlayout

I'm trying to insert a new panel into another panel in runtime everytime I press a button. My problem is the original panel runs out of space and I can't see the new panels I'm adding.

What I've tried so far:

- Using scrollpane for vertical scrolling with no success.
- Using flowlayout-no luck. Tried disabling horizontal scrolling-keep pushing the new panel to the right (can't get to it because there is no scrolling).
- Tried using borderlayout-no luck.

---

```
testpanel t = new testpanel();
t.setVisible(true);
this.jPanel15.add(t);   
this.jPanel15.validate();
this.jPanel15.repaint();
```

This code suppose to insert the `t` panel into `jpanel15`.
With flowlayout it pushes the `t` panel downwards just like I want it to but with no vertical scroll.

PS: I'm using netbeans in order to create my GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `JScrollPane` instead of the (outer) `JPanel`
2. Or have a `BorderLayout` for the `JPanel`, put in a `JScrollPane` at `BorderLayout.CENTER` as the only control. The `JScrollPane` takes a regular `JPanel` as view.

---

In any case you will then add the control to the `JScrollPane`. Suppose your `JScrollPane` variable is `spn`, your control to add is ctrl:

```
// Creation of the JScrollPane: Make the view a panel, having a BoxLayout manager for the Y-axis
JPanel view = new JPanel( );
view.setLayout( new BoxLayout( view, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
JScrollPane spn = new JScrollPane( view );

// The component you wish to add to the JScrollPane
Component ctrl = ...;

// Set the alignment (there's also RIGHT_ALIGNMENT and CENTER_ALIGNMENT)
ctrl.setAlignmentX( Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );

// Adding the component to the JScrollPane
JPanel pnl = (JPanel) spn.getViewport( ).getView( );
pnl.add( ctrl );
pnl.revalidate( );
pnl.repaint( );
spn.revalidate( );
```

Comment: Note that in case 1/ the view for the JScrollPane is also a JPanel. You will have to set the alignment for added controls yourself, eg <code>ctrl.setAlignmentX( Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );</code>

Comment: 'JPanel pnl = (JPanel) spn.getViewport( ).getView( );' return null.it doesnt return a panel.I added JScrollPane to my main panel and copied the rest of the code above but get null pointer exception.

Comment: You will have to create the JScrollPane as `JScrollPane spn = new JScrollPane( new JPanel( ) )`. That's what I mean by setting the view as a JPanel (the parameter in the constructor is called view for a reason). You can set the scroll-pane as your content pane in case your container derives from RootPaneContainer (eg JFrame or JDialog).

Comment: after done what you suggested,I can add the panel into the ScrollPane,but every new panel that i add,appears to the right of the previous panel and not below it.

Comment: Do this first before setting the view: `JPanel view = new JPanel( ); view.setLayout( new BoxLayout( view, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) ); JScrollPane spn = new JScrollPane( view );`. Then for the panels you add, make sure you set the alignment as I outlined in my previous comment. Then add the panels to the view as I outlined in my original post. HTH. If it works, please make sure to upvote this answer... I want to get credit if it does :)

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is the original panel runs out of space and I cant see the new panels i'm adding. Tried using scrollpane for vertical scrolling with no success.

A FlowLayout adds components horizontally, not vertically so you will never see vertical scrollbars. Instead you can try the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

The basic code to create the scrollpane would be:

```
JPanel main = new JPanel( new WrapLayout() );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( main );
frame.add(scrollPane);
```

Then when you dynamically add components to the main panel you would do:

```
main.add(...);
main.revalidate();
main.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```